# Ajax doesn't return JSON but an object

Tags: json, wcf, jquery, slickgrid

I want to load data from WCF to a grid (SlickGrid). This code works if I manually make a Json and load it in the grid. But if I use the variable I get from Jquery - ajax I get an object insted of an array.

If I run the following code.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataService.svc/DoWork",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: loadData,
        error: showError
    });
});

function loadData(result) {
    var data = [];
        data[0] = {
            BO: "Task ",
            Agreement: "5 days"
        };
    console.log(data);
    console.log(result);
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
}
```

I have 2 console logs. The first log is the Json I made. The second is the Json Ajax returns. Chrome tells me this is an object instead of an array(Json).

How can I convert the object (result) to a array structure like data?
[image]

Comment: `result.doWork` will be the array that you want

Comment: Have you tried using `$.parseJSON(result)`?

Comment: @PrasathK If I do console.log(result.doWork); I get unidentified in the logs

Comment: @BasitSaeed if I do console.log($.parseJSON(result)); I get null in the console

Comment: Make sure how your JSON looks in a browser ...

Comment: var data = [];
data[0] = result.d;

Comment: @Cracker0dks True this works for the object d but in the future there wil be more objects...

Comment: What do you get when you take a console log of `result` in `loadData`?

Comment: `DataService.svc/DoWork` say What you get in a browser..?

Comment: Moreover, try changing `dataType` to HTML and encode the data in JSON you're sending to this AJAX function. It works for me like this in PHP.

Comment: @BasitSaeed in the screenshot I posted its the Object: {d: Object}

Comment: @PrasathK I get method not aloud, but as you can see in the log I get something from this directory. weird... http://localhost:37177/DataService.svc/DoWork

Comment: dataType: "JSON" will automatically evaluate your JSON string to an object. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a .d after result. This returns the right object for the SlickGrid.

```
function loadData(result) {
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", result.d, columns, options); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing line:

```
var data = [];
```

to:

```
 var data = new Array();
```

inside function  loadData

Comment: It works with the data var. now I want to use the result converted into an array like data.

Comment: use push to place each element inside new array

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [];
    for(var i in result) {
        data.push(result[i]);
    }
```

(if D is not enough)